# How to create a dictionary while iterating through a nested dictionary in python?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a default dict which is a nested dictionary. I want to iterate through the dict in order to create two separate dicts left_dict and right_dict. Can someone please help to do that?

```
left_dict = {}
right_dict = {}
d1 = {'A': {'left': {'10.xxx.77.1': [5]}, 'right': {'10.xxx.77.2': [6]}}, 'B': {'left': {'10.xxx.77.1': [7]}, 'right': {'10.xxx.77.2': [8]}}}
d = defaultdict(list)
for k , v in d1.items():
    if isinstance(v, dict):
        for j, l in v.items():
            if isinstance(l, dict):
                for m, n in l.items():
                    d[m].append(n)
print(d)
```

Actual output is

```
{'10.xxx.77.1': [[5], [7]], '10.xxx.77.2': [[6], [8]]}
```

Expected output is

```
left_dict = {'10.xxx.77.1': [5, 7]}
right_dict = {'10.xxx.77.2': [6, 8]}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "too long"?  You can't really argue with code that works.  You should try using `extend` instead of `append` in your last line.

Comment: @TimRoberts, I have modified my question. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: @Tim Roberts What's the point of using `extend`? Isn't `+=` functionally identical when joining lists?

Comment: Yes.  Same purpose, different spelling, but only because `+=` is special-cased for lists.  If you did `d[m] = d[m] + n`, that would create a new list, which is wasteful.

Comment: @TimRoberts, extend is not working and I have changed the problem statement in the question, can you take a look at it again once?

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is your goal.

```py
#left_dict = {}
#right_dict = {}
d1 = {'A': {'left': {'10.xxx.77.1': [5]}, 'right': {'10.xxx.77.2': [6]}}, 'B': {'left': {'10.xxx.77.1': [7]}, 'right': {'10.xxx.77.2': [8]}}}
d = {}
for k, dict1 in d1.items():
    if not isinstance(dict1, dict):
        continue
    for pos, dict2 in dict1.items():
        if not isinstance(dict2, dict):
            continue
        if not isinstance(d.get(pos, None), dict):
            d[pos]={}
        for port, v_list in dict2.items():
            d[pos][port]=d[pos].get(port, [])+v_list
            
print(d)
# {'left': {'10.xxx.77.1': [5, 7]}, 'right': {'10.xxx.77.2': [6, 8]}}
```

Answer (score 0):

**I think below code will serve your purpose:**

```
d1 = {
  'A': {'left': {'10.xxx.77.1': [5]}, 'right': {'10.xxx.77.2': [6]}},
  'B': {'left': {'10.xxx.77.1': [7]}, 'right': {'10.xxx.77.2': [8]}},
  'C': {'left': {'10.xxx.77.1': [9, 11]}, 'right': {'10.xxx.77.2': [10, 12]}}
}
d = {}
left_dict = {}
right_dict = {}

for k , v in d1.items():
    for j, l in v.items():
        if not isinstance(d.get(j), dict):
            d[j] = {}
        for m, n in l.items():
            d[j][m] = d[j].get(m, []) + n

left_dict = d.get('left')
right_dict = d.get('right')

print(d)
print(f'left_dict = {left_dict}\nright_dict = {right_dict}')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```
# Stores values to left and right dicts
def fill_dict(src_d, des_d):
    for k, v in src_d.items():
        if k not in des_d:
            des_d[k] = v
        else:
            des_d[k].extend(v)


left_dict = {}
right_dict = {}
d1 = {'A': {'left': {'10.xxx.77.1': [5]}, 'right': {'10.xxx.77.2': [6]}}, 'B': {'left': {'10.xxx.77.1': [7]}, 'right': {'10.xxx.77.2': [8]}}}

for k , v in d1.items():
    for ks, vs in v.items():
        if ks == 'left':
            fill_dict(vs, left_dict)
        elif ks == 'right':
            fill_dict(vs, right_dict)
        

print(left_dict)
print(right_dict)
```

```
Output

{'10.xxx.77.1': [5, 7]}
{'10.xxx.77.2': [6, 8]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved using a recursive function and designed for flexibility (i.e. it's overly complicated for what was asked but I enjoyed the practice).

1. regardless of key depth, the function will extract the corresponding value/s
2. attempts to assemble those values by combining them or simply appending

```
# added additional depth to demo input dictionary
dictionary_li = [{'A': {'C': {'left': {'10.xxx.77.1': [5]}, 'right': {'10.xxx.77.2': [6]}}}, 'B': {'left': {'10.xxx.77.1': [7]}, 'right': {'10.xxx.77.2': [8]}}}]

def recursive_key_search(dictionary_li, key, key_di):
    '''extract values belonging to key'''
    flatten_li = []
    for di in dictionary_li:
        for k in di:
            if key not in di and di[k]:
                flatten_li.append(di[k])
            else:
                if key not in key_di:
                    key_di[key] = []
                elif di[key] not in key_di[key]: # key can occur at different depths
                    key_di[key].append(di[key]) # no assumptions on format made at this time
    # check if additional iteration necessary
    if sum([1 for di in flatten_li for k in di if type(di[k]) == dict]) > 0:
        recursive_key_search(flatten_li, key, key_di)
    return(key_di)


def merge_dictionaries(flatten_li, merge=False):
    '''merge values within dictionary'''
    out_di = {}
    for di in flatten_li:
        for k in di:
            # will attempt to combine values
            if merge:
                if k not in out_di:
                    out_di[k] = di[k]
                elif type(di[k]) == type(out_di[k]):
                    out_di[k] += di[k]
                else:
                    out_di[k].append(di[k])
            # will keep values separated
            else:
                if k not in out_di:
                    out_di[k] = []
                out_di[k].append(di[k])
    return(out_di)


for key in ["left", "right"]:
    key_search = recursive_key_search(dictionary_li, key, {})[key]
    #print(key_search)
    merge = merge_dictionaries(key_search, True)
    print(key+":", merge)
```

**Output**

```
left: {'10.xxx.77.1': [7, 5]}
right: {'10.xxx.77.2': [8, 6]}
```